# Firebase Facebook or Google login does not redirect back to my page

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am using Firebase for Facebook and Google login from a site hosted by AppEngine. 
When I want to login, it prompted me to Facebook login page, after entering my credentials it hangs in Firebase redirect page (gray window). There is no error message at all. I made sure following all steps listed in Firebase site. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html

My code is as following:

```
var ref = new Firebase("my firebase domain");
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          } else {
            console.log("Success!");  
            console.log(authData.facebook.accessToken);
          }
        });
```

I made sure the domain I am making this call is listed in Firebase settings. I tried adding localhost and making call from there, but I still see the same issue.

Looks like Firebase does not redirect back to my page with authData retrieved from Facebook or Google.

Do you know why this might be happening? What is the solution?

Comment: Try reaching out to Firebase support at support@firebase.com with your application details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to why this was happening.

I was setting href in the login  tag in html to do the domain root which
refreshed the page, and causing connection to child window to break. I made the following change to fix it.

> < a href="#" onclick="login()">Facebook Login < /a